# Custom Joomla plugin to catch specific database queries

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, database, plugin-events

Is it possible to make a plugin which will get triggered by specific database events in Joomla?

I need to watch the `$this->getTable()` request in Joomla. For eg:

```
$table = $this->getTable();
if ($table->load($id)).....
```

I have to catch this event to modify the `$table` before `$table->load($id)` happens. The reason that I want to use a plugin doing, is that I don't want to do directly changes in the Joomla core code. My thoughts are that this could be possible with a plugin?

Comment: There isn't a plugin event that is watching when Joomla is dealing with the Database. To be honest I don't make much sense of your question. Maybe you could add more context about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: In my custom component I would like to store my user data in a custom table. Therefore I did a custom authentication plugin and a custom user plugin, which are responsible for separate registering and login to the custom component. Authentication and login is working. My last problem is, opening the new view after login in, that the $app->redirect(JRoute::_($redirect_url) command in a component subcontroller initialize a load of the original Joomla User Table to check the User. And on this place the whole idea and the whole effort fails. It is not checking the session nor the custom plugins.

Comment: So isn't any of the [**User Plugin Events**](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User) suitable for your purpose?

Comment: The problem is as mentioned above, the public function load($id) in ../libraries/src/User/User.php line 877, which will be called after the $app->redirect. I don't know why this function will be called. In this function the authenticated user to my custom plugins will be downgraded as guest and finally dropped out. I'am a bit frustrated!

Comment: Then there is likely something wrong with your plugins which you need to fix.

Comment: do you have any suggentions how to inspect and solve the problem? Of course I trace every step with xdebug! But as I can see, there is no place outside the core, where I can take influence to work around this function.

Comment: What I suggest is to create another question where you will explain exactly your real problem: present your code, your efforts, the errors you get and what is the desired/expected result. As this current question looks more of an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type of question and doesn't seem to lead anywhere. With a new question to the point of your problem, you will have more chances to get proper answers.